# MultiThreading Variables C# -- Selenium

Tags: c#, multithreading, object, selenium, parameter-passing

I am trying to automate the test for one of my websites using Selenium on C#. The website prompts the user for login credentials. It can only be done through multi threading.
I execute one thread to open the page in a special FireFox profile and another thread in parallel to simulate the press of <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

The problem is the if I don't use multi threading, the code stops at opening the page as the website is not completely opened. 
The driver is initiated in the first thread created. However it has to be used in the main method.
How can I pass an object created in a method (executed by a thread) in the main function?

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Windows.Forms; 

namespace CRMTest1WithSelenium
{
    class Program
    {
       public static IWebDriver OpenPage()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = null;
            string path = @"C:\Users\ntouma\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\nuxgc36b.CRMTester"; 
            FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile(path); 
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.example.com");
            return driver;
        }

        public static void pressEnter()
       {
           Thread.Sleep(6000);
           System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
       }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver2 = null;
            driver2 = OpenPage();

           // Thread driverCreation = new Thread(OpenPage);
           // driverCreation.Start();
            Thread login = new Thread(pressEnter);
            login.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            driver2.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            IWebElement sales = driver2.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[4]/d"));
            sales.Click();

            IWebElement leads = driver2.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body//div/div/ul/li[3]/span/span[2]/span/span[1]/span/a[1]"));
            leads.Click();

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't understand your problem in 100%...
But i can suggest two solutions:
1) Use a static member that your login functions will use inside it.
2) Send a class(object) to the thread when you create one:
e.g:

```
var myObj = ...; Thread thread = new Thread(() => pressEnter(myObj)); thread.Start();
```

Comment: My problem is:
I want to use "driver" created in OpenPage() in the main method. But OpenPage() must be ran by a thread. and that is causing problems. 
Is it any clearer now?

Comment: What is your .net framework version?? Meanwhile you can arise an event from OpenPage() that will execute your code.